# Splitting csv strings and display it in different fields?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

So basically I'm designing a report which can record name and amount of individuals. Now, I have no idea how to implement this on my cr report. But I need to split the csv strings and put all the splitted value as columns.

Here is my sample cell

[image: Sample Cell]

I have 2 sample columns, Name and amounts. Both columns represent individual cell. Name is a single cell seperated by newline and same as amount.

[image: my desired data]

In my desired output, I need to split all the values inside cell "Name" and put it in different column in Crystal Report and i also need to display the values of "Amount" Below the "Name". Which    splitting is needed

Can this be theoretically be done? Any help is appreciated!
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply use the menu option of **Insert, CrossTab...** to insert a crosstab in the report header or footer.

Select ***Name*** as the column field.

Select ***Amount*** as the field to summarize.

Comment: any way to display name? I'm trying to put in the column field but doesn't show as it is a string field

Comment: A string is perfectly acceptable as a column field.
Please clarify what exactly you are seeing when trying to set the Name column as the column field in the croisstab. Perhaps include an image.